# Producer/Consumer: Consumer needs to remove elements from the shared Queue

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an issue with an application I am developing.
I have two threads, Prod and Cons, which respectively write to and read from a shared `Queue`. All pretty standard here.
The goal of this application is for Prod to read a file and add each line to the `Queue`, while Cons will have to read these lines and "match" them in pairs (following some criteria).

The problem is that, for Cons to do its part, it will have to "process" several lines from the  `Queue` and remove only the ones that form a Pair.
For example, if the following is the `Queue` Q as filled by Prod:

```
Q:
-
A1  
A2  
B1  
C1  
D1  
C2  
D2    
B2  
E1  
E2
```

Cons should create Pairs (A1,A2),(B1,B2),(C1,C2), etc... (The order of the pair is a requirement).

My problem is that, to create Pair (B1,B2), Cons will need first to analyze C1, D1, D2 and C2 and find that they don't match B1; then B2 is found and both B1 and B2 must be removed from Q, without modifying the order of the previous non-matching elements (C1, D1, etc...).
At the moment, I resolved with Cons removing always the first element from the Queue and, if that doesn't match, it's saved in an additional internal queue in Cons; when a matching element is found, the Pair is created and all elements saved in the internal queue are "reinjected" at the head of Q (which is actually a `DeQue`).

While this approach works for simple situations, it is hopelessly flawed. Given that Prod keeps running, it can well happen that, while Cons removes non-matching elements, Prod adds new lines, effectively generating a deadlock the moment when Cons will try to reinsert messages on Q.

I also thought that Cons could only "peek" at the elements in Q and remove only the matching one, but that would mean accessing a specific element (e.g. random access like) in the `Deque`.

Does anybody have suggestion for the problem? I can always "create" an `Deque` that does what I need, but I would really prefer not! Too error prone...

Thanks!

Comment: One detail more: I always have only ONE Producer and ONE Consumer.

Comment: You could use a `LinkedList` to do the trick since this class implements both `Queue` and `List`. So you could still use `offer()` and `poll()` and be able to access random elements in the list

Comment: But that would lose the synchronization between Prod and Cons....I can work that out with manual synchronization I guess...

Comment: why would you loose the sync? The producer would still offer items to your `LinkedList` while the consumer searches it for matches and takes only the matching pairs. everything else remains untouched

Comment: I just mean that I would have to manually code it instead of using it for free from BlockingQueue and similar. I can sure do it, I just wanted to be sure that was the only solution

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can split up the lines into several categories (or buckets) by looking only at a single line (i.e. each of the line types do have a distinct format) you could keep using a BlockingQueue to connect the producer and consumer.

For each line the consumer reads from the queue it determines the correct bucket of the line and uses a Linked(Hash)Map to either

- store it, if no line is already stored in the bucket
- produces a pair with the line already stored in the map and emit it

After the queue is exhausted, the consumer will have produced all pairs encountered and the consumer's LinkedMap holds all lines that were not paired, in insertion order.

That would encapsulate the matching inside the consumer, keeping the clear separation of concerns between producer, consumer and the queue connecting them.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how matching is performed (e.g. if given a "C1" you know that the match must be a "C2" as opposed to a "C146" or whatever), it may make sense to replace the Queue with a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) with "C1" and "C2" etc as the keys.  The producer adds elements to a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) (with no maximum capacity), while the consumer polls the queue and uses `ContainsKey` on the hashmap to determine if a matching element is already in the map; if there's a match then the matching element is removed from the map, otherwise the current element is added to the map.  When the consumer finishes processing all of the producers data, the LinkedHashMap will have an ordered list of all unmatched elements.  Just make sure that you're able to match "C2" to "C1" as well as being able to match "C1" to "C2"

```
public class SharedCollections {
    public static LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> workList = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
}

public class Producer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            SharedCollections.workList.offer(obj);
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Object obj = SharedCollections.workList.take(); // blocks if the workList is empty
            String matchingId = getMatchingId(obj.id); // e.g. returns "C2" if the object's id is "C1"
            if(hashMap.containsKey(matchingId)) {
                hashMap.remove(matchingId);
            } else {
                hashMap.put(obj.id, obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using two distinct collections will make the addition and removal non-atomic. That could produce hard to track bugs.

Comment: It sounds like the producer is just blindly adding elements (i.e. without using peek or get first), so it ought to be unaffected by the consumer's behavior.  The consumer will need to be more careful, because it's likely that map.get(match) will return false followed by the producer adding a match, but this can be fixed by iterating through the map's keys again; the map might also have a map.get(match) that returns true prior to the producer adding the match to the queue, so when the consumer calls queue.remove(match) it will need to do this in a loop to ensure that match has been added first

Comment: The latter synchronization problem won't occur of the producer always adds to the queue prior to adding to the map, although this will slightly increase the probability that the consumer will miss matches on the first pass through the keys